# Help me with this Olympiad problem

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

A diagonal $D$ is chosen on a $n$ x $n$ grid. The diagonal goes from the upper left corner to the lower right corner of the grid dividing it into to congruent triangular regions as shown in the picture below.

[image]

The squares of $D$ and the squares of one of the triangular regions are coloured with $n$ different colors (the colors for $D$ and of the regions are the same) and then the other triangular region is coloured symmetrically to the part that has already been coloured as if D were a mirror. Here is a case for $n=3$ (but it is not valid in this case since all of the colors aren't used).

[image]

If $3 \leq n \leq 25 $, for which values of $n$ is it possible to color a $n$ x $n$ this way if no colors can be repeated in $D$, in any row and on any column.

I could just find that $n$ had to be an odd number. Since no colors can be repeated on a column, each of the $n$ colors appear once in each column, therefore each color appears $n$ times. Now suppose you place color $A$ in the upper left corner (on the diagonal), and let's say that color appears "$x$" times in one of the triangular regions, as both regions are symmetric it also appears $x$ times in the other regions, now that color appears $2x+1$ times, and since $n$ = (# of times a specific color appears), $n=2x+1$, therefore $n$ is odd.

I do not know how to put the tag to this question, so I'll put game theory, let me know if there is a tag for this question.

Comment: Conversely, you can color the square with each odd $n$: Number the colors by $0, 1, \cdots, n-1$. On the $(i,j)$-cell, paint it with the color $i+j \pmod n$.

Comment: (+1) go make that into an answer?